# browsercore32 processes not getting cleared in Dotnetbrowser

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I'm using dotnetbrowser control in Windows form application. I've following requirement

- Display browser content in Windows form pop up
- User interacts & click on finish button within rendered application
- This event is captured using status event which eventually polls url
- I'm calling Close(); method within StatusChangedEvent
- It closes form but I can still see browsercore32.exe process in Task Mangager --> processes , that causes main application termination issue

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't dispose of your Browser instance after closing the form.
But it's necessary to dispose of all `Browser` and `BrowserView` instances after using.

This [article](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000109699-disposing-browser) explains how to dispose DotNetBrowser.